# Why is my PyTorch code 10x slower than the TensorFlow version?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, pytorch, neural-network

I'm trying to learn how to optimize models and have written some simple fashion MNIST training in TF and PyTorch to see how they compare when run on CPU vs GPU. My environment is a Windows PC, i7-10, 16GB RAM, 2060 GPU with 6GB dedicated RAM, and Python 3.10. Both sets of code give me about 88% accuracy after 10 epochs (although accuracy is not what I'm after for this - I'm looking to understand perf). But the TF training takes 21 seconds on the CPU, while the PT code takes about 128 seconds regardless if I run it on the CPU or GPU.

Any help you can give me on what I'm doing wrong on PyTorch would be appreciated.

OK; here's the TF code run on a straight CPU (without WSL):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
RANDOM_SEED = 12    # 12th man - go Seahawks!
tf.random.set_seed(RANDOM_SEED)

BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 10

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train/255.0
x_test  = x_test/255.0

def get_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model = get_model()
    current_time = tf.timestamp()
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
    elapsed_time = tf.timestamp() - current_time
    print (f"CPU Training time: {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")

# Print accuracy and loss on the test set
test_acc, test_loss = model.evaluate(x_test,  y_test, verbose=0)
print(f"Test accuracy: {test_acc:.4f}, loss: {test_loss:.4f}")
```

Here are the typical last few lines of output showing training time and accuracy:

```
CPU Training time: 20.28 seconds  
Test accuracy: 0.8827, loss: 0.3308
```

Here is my attempt at an equivalent PT code. Note I've tested by explicitly changing the device to "CPU" at the top (vs default run which sets it to cuda for my 2060 in my environment), and it makes little difference:

```py
import time
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
device = "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu"
print (f"Using device: {device}")

DIR = "data/fashionmnist"
RANDOM_SEED = 12    # 12th man - go Seahawks!
BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 10

# Fix random seeds for reproducibility
torch.manual_seed(RANDOM_SEED)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(RANDOM_SEED)
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic=True

model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Flatten(),
    nn.Linear(28*28, 256),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Dropout(0.3),
    nn.Linear(256, 128),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(128, 10)
    ).to(device)

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())

# Get the fashion mnist training data and normalize it
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))])
train = datasets.FashionMNIST(DIR, download=True, train=True, transform=transform)
train_loader = DataLoader(train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, pin_memory=True)

def train_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    avg_loss = 0
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
        # Compute prediction error
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)
        avg_loss += loss.item()
        # Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    return avg_loss / size

current_time = time.time()
for t in range(EPOCHS):
    print(f"Epoch {t+1}...", end="")
    avg_loss = train_loop(train_loader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
    print(f"Avg loss: {avg_loss:.4f}")
elapsed_time = time.time() - current_time
print (f"{device} Training time: {elapsed_time:.2f} seconds")

def test_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
            pred = model(X)
            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, y).item()
            correct += (pred.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).sum().item()
    test_loss /= size
    correct /= size
    print(f"Accuracy: {(100*correct):>0.1f}%, Avg loss: {test_loss:>8f} \n")
test = datasets.FashionMNIST(DIR, download=True, train=False, transform=transform)
test_loader = DataLoader(test, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False)
test_loop(test_loader, model, loss_fn)

print("Done!")
```

Here are the typical last few lines of output showing training time and accuracy:

```
cuda Training time: 127.91 seconds  
Accuracy: 87.1%, Avg loss: 0.005769
```

If I set the device to CPU (instead of letting it default to cuda) I get a similar result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely experiencing this issue due to data loading speed. Please notice that:

- `tensorflow` has **whole dataset** in RAM memory in your case (`X_train` and `y_train`
- `pytorch` loads batch of images **from disk** (see `FashionMNIST` source code [here](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/_modules/torchvision/datasets/mnist.html#FashionMNIST)), saves them, later changes them to PIL image and than converts to `torch.Tensor` instances again

For future readers, here is the relevant snippet:

```
def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Tuple[Any, Any]:
    img, target = self.data[index], int(self.targets[index])

    # doing this so that it is consistent with all other datasets
    # to return a PIL Image

    # This one gets numpy array, converts to PIL image and then
    # converts to to PyTorch tensor again due to compatibility as mentioned above
    img = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), mode="L")

    if self.transform is not None:
        img = self.transform(img)

    if self.target_transform is not None:
        target = self.target_transform(target)

    return img, target
```

Given the above, I would create a custom `torch.utils.data.Dataset` which:

- Loads images as `torch.Tensor`
- Simply returns them in `__getitem__`

Additionally `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` is another abstraction (although light and should not affect the scores), but might be something worth ruling out. In such case, you can simply batch by slicing `64` elements from the `torch.utils.data.Dataset`.

Other possible things slowing down PyTorch:

- using `transforms` - it is done per-batch, while in case of `keras` you are doing it only once, you should do the data preprocessing similarly in both cases as it's likely to be the bottleneck
- using `torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic=True` (see [reproducibility](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html))
- check how many epochs you are using. GPU might be underutilized for last batch, although this is probably noise and IIRC `keras` is not dropping last batch either (`torch.utils.data.DataLoader` `drop_last=True` argument [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html))

Comment: Thank you!!!

The PyTorch MNIST dataset was indeed the bottleneck, and creating a custom dataset that creates normalized tensors at __init__ time resulted in similar performance to tensorflow.

I will say; the amount of code needed was about 3x more with PyTorch than with tensorflow.